# Cannot set date in beforeCreate hook - Strapi (beta14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

Created a news model: News.js

```
beforeCreate: async (model, attrs) => {
  if (attrs['Date'] === null) {
    model.set('Date', '2030-00-00 00:00:00+00');
  }
}
```

When i create the post, if user didn't fill date field i want it to be pre-filled automatically. But `model.set()` seems to have no effect when i create a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `beforeSave` function.

```
beforeSave: async (model, attrs, options) => {
  // detect if it's a creation or an update
  if (options.method === 'insert') {
    // statement for creation
    if (attrs['Date'] === null) {
      model.set('Date', '2030-00-00 00:00:00+00');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you plan to publish documentation regards this case?

Comment: Yes! We are currently working on documentation examples to help more strapi users.

Comment: Still no documentation regards this, Jim.

Comment: You can check this guide https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/slug.html#configure-the-layout-for-the-content-editor

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing model directly, mutate `attrs`.

```
beforeCreate: async (model, attrs) => {
  if (attrs['Date'] === null) {
    attrs['Date'] = '2030-00-00 00:00:00+00';
  }
}
```